# Use of Norton theorem to find short circuit current

Tags: circuit-analysis, norton

In the given circuit, while finding Norton or Short circuit current, we short terminal A and B. So I have assumed that is(t) = short circuit current.
Is it correct to assume so?
I did it because as terminal A and B are short circuit, all the current is(t) has zero resistance path to ground. Is my analysis correct?[image]

Comment: What about the voltage source?

Comment: Yes, What about it?

Comment: it also provides current.

Comment: Yes, of course it does, but that results in current flowing through C1 and other elements. But the short circuit current through terminal AB will remain is(t). Is that not correct?

Comment: draw the short circuit. What happens to L2? What about the current through L2?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks @user110971! Got it now. But then how do we find short circuit current?

Comment: well, it is the current source plus whatever is passing through L2. You have R||L. The voltage source forms a voltage divider. Once you get the voltage, you can calculate the current. Use phasors, I guess.

Comment: I had already calculated the voltage at the middle node, so that made it easy to calculate current through L2. Now added it with is(t) to get short circuit current.
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

We're using superposition to establish the short circuit curent. When ignoring \$i_1\$ we can calculate the impedance between terminals A and B:

$$ Z_{AB} = j \omega L_2 + \frac{1}{j \omega C + 1/R} $$

leading to a current of
$$ i_{u1} = \frac{u_1}{Z_{AB}} = \frac{u_1}{j \omega L_2 + \frac{1}{j \omega C + 1/R}}$$

This is the first partial current. Now, if we consider \$i_1\$ and replace \$u_1\$ with a short circuit, \$i_1\$ is connected directly between terminals A and B. Thus:

$$ i_{short} = i_1 + i_{u1} $$

So you are half correct. The short circuit current consists of a part \$i_1\$ and a part \$i_{u1}\$ contributed by the voltage source.